# Enable PPTP notification-area icon in Windows 8?

Tags: networking, windows-8, notification-area

Is there a way to enable icon **in taskbar tray of Windows 8 displaying whether PPTP is currently connected or not?**

It occassionally happens that PPTP connection drops and icon showing connection status would be useful. In earlier Windows versions, I could find checkbox [image] but I can't find thing like that in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that **notifications for all networks** were in Windows 8 moved into single network connection tooltip:

[image]

Not very practical but obviously in Windows 8 there is **only one connection icon**. It shows Wi-Fi or Ethernet symbol based on which connection is active.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but finally I sat down for 4 hours at my PC and wrote simple .NET tool PING-ing configured IP address and displaying connection status via icon in notification area (taskbar tray).